# HttpClient PutAsync doesn't send a parameter to api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, json.net

On the controller Put is as following:

```
[HttpPut]
[ActionName("putname")]
public JsonResult putname(string name)
{
    var response = ...
    return Json(response);  
}
```

The issue is on the when consuming this API via following

```
using (httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    string name = "abc";
    string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(name);
    var requestUrl = new Uri("http:...../controller/putname/");
    using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString))
    {
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PutAsync(requestUrl, httpContent).Result;
    }
```

This code doesn't pass the parameter name to controller. I even tried changeing uri to /putname/" + name.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is what works for me:

```
var jsonString = "{\"appid\":1,\"platformid\":1,\"rating\":3}";
var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");            
var message = await _client.PutAsync(MakeUri("App/Rate"), httpContent);
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, message.StatusCode);
```

and my action method:

```
public void PutRate(AppRating model)
{
   if (model == null)
      throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     // ..
   }      
}
```

and the model

```
public class AppRating
{
    public int AppId { get; set; }
    public int PlatformId { get; set; }
    public decimal Rating { get; set; }
}
```

-Stan

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think what you said should work. Following is what I did.                                                    var cUri = new Uri("http://localhost/cart/coupon");
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { id = "abc" });
HttpResponseMessage cartResponse;
using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString))
{
 httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
cartResponse = httpClient.PostAsync(cUri, httpContent).Result;              }

Comment: I am using same thing as you proposed as answer but not working.

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked correctly:

```
            string requestUrl = endpointUri + "/Files/";
            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { name = "newFile.txt", type = "File" }); 

            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(jsonString);
            httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue ("application/json");          

            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();

            //add the header with the access token
            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            //make the put request
            HttpResponseMessage hrm = (await hc.PostAsync(requestUrl, httpContent));

            if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               //stuff
            }
```

Comment: But this is for PostAsync. OP was asking about PutAsync