# Adding an object to a httpclient put

Tags: c#, rest, dotnet-httpclient, put

I am trying to make a put request to an API. My code so far is -

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress)
        };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", token);


var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", id.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("customer_group", group.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("customer_permission", permission),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("prefered_timezone", timezone)
        });

        var response = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
```

The problem I am having is I need to add a values field too. Where the data will look like -

```
values: [
0: {values: "+447500000000", field: 1082, user: 218218}
1: {values: "test", field: 1084, user: 218218}
2: {values: "name", field: 1085, user: 218218}]
```

I have tried creating an object for this but encounter problems due to using FormUrlEncodedContent. What is an alternative way? Also I cannot use third party NuGet packages.

Comment: Did you check this out; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489611/httpclient-putasync-doesnt-send-a-parameter-to-api

Comment: In your headers, your indicating that you're sending "application/json". But in your code, you are defining FormUrlEncondedContent, which, I believe, is a different content type, and only allows for key value pairs (no nested objects, like your required 'values' property). I would try replacing your 'content' variable with a custom object that matches the data structure specified by the api.

Comment: It completely depends on API you're requesting. Is it your ASP.NET or third party API?

Comment: @AndrewCastellano How would I create the custom object? This seems like it would be my best choice.

Comment: either define a class, or inline:
var content = new { 
id = id.ToString(), email = email, customer_group = group.ToString(), customer_permission = permission, preferred_timezone = timezone, values = new List<Object> { new { values = "test", field = 1084, user = 218218 }, new { values = "name", field = 1085, user = 218218} } }

I haven't checked this syntax, but hopefully the idea is there. I can clarify if needed.

Comment: Could you please tell what `baseAddress` does contain?

Comment: @AndrewCastellano I tried the inline way, when I try add the content to the putAsync request I get an error saying cannot convert from Systems.Collections.Generic.List<object> values to System.Net.Http.HttpContent.

Comment: @sunnyj58 I mean what concrete base url are you currently working with? If you use your C# web application api I can help. If it is some other third party I'll investigate this.

Comment: could try:
var response = await client.PutAsync(url, new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(content));

Comment: can you post your latest code?

Comment: Solved. I did this -
StringContent content = new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");